# How to handle cookies across domains in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, session-cookies

I developed two rails apps, they will each go on `site.com` and `something.site.com` respectively. In development mode they are run on `localhost:3000` and `localhost:4000`, you must be logged into `site.com` to access `something.site.com`.

I have the cookies set up to handle domains from `:all`, and the tests all pass in relation to creating and destroying sessions. How ever I am unfamiliar how to test the cookies with out actually deploying the apps to production. I don't have staging servers, their small basic apps and I don't want them public. Is their any ways, on my mac, I can test (by launching both apps) the domain specific cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your hosts file located at `/etc/hosts` to point 127.0.0.1 to local.site.com and then access your rails apps at local.site.com:3000 and local.site.com:4000

`127.0.0.1 localhost local.site.com`

Comment: This didn't actually work. The cookie is set in `local.site.com:4000` but is never seen in `local.site.com:3000` I an unsure if its a code error or if this is the wrong way to test this

Comment: Are you trying to access a plain text cookie or the rails session cookie?

Comment: the rails session cookie via: `current_user` which defined as such: `@current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token(cookies.signed[:auth_token]) if cookies.signed[:auth_token]` This works for `local.site.com:4000` by returning a current user, how ever for local.site.com:3000 this will return nil .... (both apps have the same user in their database, with the same auth token.)

Comment: `cookies.signed` signs the cookie with your rails app's secret token to prevent users from tampering with them. In order for signed cookies to be compatible between rails applications, the secret token must match. So make sure the secret tokens are the same in `config/initializers/secret_token.rb`.

This might not be super safe though...

Comment: is there a better, more safe way to do this?

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily super bad to do this, the one thing you must never do is share your secret_token with javascript code. The main drawback to tying secret_tokens together is if you have to change one secret token for whatever reason, you have to remember to change the other. One approach would be to store the secret_token in an environment variable, see this link for more details: http://daniel.fone.net.nz/blog/2013/05/20/a-better-way-to-manage-the-rails-secret-token/.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you could update your hosts file to point something.localhost to 127.0.0.1

`127.0.0.1 something.localhost` in `/etc/hosts

I'm sure you've read that as long as the TLD is the same, this should work.

Comment: dah! someone beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

Look at using POW and Powder.  Runs slower, but allows you to run concurrent apps on localhost.

[Pow User's Manual](http://pow.cx/manual.html)